# Testing Akka Actor with org.scalatest

Tags: akka, actor, scalatest

```
class Scheduler(repository : Repository) extends Actor
{
override def receive : Receive =
{
    case TriggerDaily => repository.deleteOlderThan1year()
    case TriggerHourly => repository.nullifyOlderThan3hrs()
}
}

object Scheduler
{
case object TriggerDaily
case object TriggerHourly

def props(repository : Repository) =
    Props(classOf[Scheduler], repository)

}
```

In this repository methods deleteOlderThan1year and deleteOlderThan1year return Future[Done]? Can anyone help me how to write unit test cases for this Scheduler Actor?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html) for testing Akka.  Essentially, you will extend `TestKit` to initialize an actor system for your actor.  Since your actor requires a `Repository` for instantiation, I'd also recommend that you look into mocking the `Repository` to verify that the appropriate method is being called.